# How can I format the command window output of a custom class in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, command-window

how can I achieve a formatted output in the command-window in Matlab when I call the object ob a custom class? The regular output of a custom class is a list of all public properties as shown below.

```
customss with properties:

    A: [8×8 double]
    B: [8×1 double]
    C: [2×8 double]
    D: [2×1 double]
```

For example, when I create a state space model in Matlab and then call the object in the command window the output is a formatted representation of the system matrices and the sample time. Even by debugging I could not figure out if possibly a certain function is call to achieve this. So, how can I create such an customized output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has a special abstract class `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` which your class can inherit to make the display behaviour customizable.

MathWorks has a [detailed documentation section](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/custom-object-display.html) covering various customizations this allows.

Comment: I don't have the Control System Toolbox to check myself, but it may be that the built in `ssm` class uses this method directly for its display format. If so, you could inspect this using `edit ssm`, or maybe specifically `edit ssm.displayPropertyGroups` to see how to match the behaviour exactly in your custom state space class.